# Batch file to rename images for WD Live TV

Tags: batch-file, file-rename

Apologies if this has been answered, the search gives something similar but not exactly what I'm after.

I use XBMC and a Western Digital TV Live as media centers.  XBMC uses `folder.jpg` for movie box art.  However, the WD uses both `folder.jpg` and `moviename.jpg`.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
Films\movie1\movie1.mkv(or avi etc...)
Films\movie1\folder.jpg
Films\movie2\movie2.mkv (etc...)
Films\movie2\folder.jpg
```

What I'm after is a .bat file that will scan the entire films directory, copy the `folder.jpg` and rename the new jpg using the name of the folder that `folder.jpg` is in.  The original `folder.jpg` should remain.

Essentially from:

```
Films\movie1\folder.jpg
```

To:

```
Films\movie1\folder.jpg
```

and

```
Films\movie1\movie1.jpg
```

This should happen to each folder in `Films`.

I'm sure this must be possible but to be honest my knowledge of `.bat` files is very limited.

Comment: So you want to *copy* `folder.jpg` rather than rename it, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `FOR /D` loop to iterate over subdirectories of `Films`:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /D %%I IN ("D:\Path\to\Films\*") DO (
  COPY "%%I\folder.jpg" "%%I\%%~nxI.jpg"
)
```

In the loop, the subdirectory's full path is referenced as `%%I` and its name alone as `%%~nxI` (could be just `%%~nI` if the name never includes a `.`).

You could run the loop directly from the command prompt, but you'd need to replace the double `%` characters with single `%`:

```
FOR /D %I IN ("D:\Path\to\Films\*") DO COPY "%I\folder.jpg" "%I\%~nxI.jpg"
```

Please note also that if a `moviename.jpg` already exists, the `COPY` command will stop for confirmation of overwriting the file. If you just want to overwrite it anyway without manual confirmation, add the `/Y` switch:

```
COPY /Y ...
```

Comment: Thank you, that does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /d %%a in (*) do if exist "%%~a\folder.jpg" echo copy /b "%%~a\folder.jpg" "%%~a\%%~na.jpg"
```

Remove the `echo` to get it working.